# Compiler shows a square with the name of the eps image rather than the image I need

Tags: floats, subfloats, epstopdf, epslatex

When I use the code, two empty squares ares shown, in each one the name of the figure are displayed, but I need the figures. How could I fix the code, to make appear the images?

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epic}
\usepackage{eepic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{comment}
%para graficas


    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!tbp]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ZTauEquilibrio.eps}
    \caption{Flower one.}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ZTauEquilibrioyCiclos_limites.eps}
    \caption{Flower two.}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't `graphicx` loaded with the `draft` option? Unrelated: you may delete `epsfig` loading: it's been obsolete for more than 20 years, and replaced with `graphicx` (`subfigure` is obsolete too and no more maintained).

Comment: @Bernard So should I erase the graphics package? I already erase it and the figures are not shown neither.

Comment: @JuanMuñoz - No, keep loading the `graphicx` package. (It's needed for the `\includegraphics` instruction.) By the way, unless your TeX distribution is about 8 years old (or older...), there should be no need to load either the `eps2pdf`package or the `epsfig` package. Finally, do check in your real document if the option `draft` is specified at the `\documentclass` stage; if that's the case, do remove the `draft` option.

Comment: @mico I erase the eps2pdf package and the images where shown, so this fix my problem. Unrelated: but when I erase the epsfig package, appears an error.

Comment: Which TeX distribution do you use?

Comment: @mico I am working in Overleaf

Comment: no epsfig just loads graphicx then defines an `\epsfig`  command that you are not using (and should not use) so you should not load it.

Answer (score -1):

Use `draftfigure` package

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epic}
\usepackage{eepic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[%
filename ,%
]{draftfigure}
%para graficas


    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!tbp]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ZTauEquilibrio.eps}
    \caption{Flower one.}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ZTauEquilibrioyCiclos_limites.eps}
    \caption{Flower two.}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the question is how to _not_ get the draft display, and show the images.